# Oval shape on the outside of a model

Tags: modeling

So I was following [Blender Guru's Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEL9UjPTLWQhLFAK7wVaRMR) on a chair and when I got to the UV unwrapping part I notices something weird going on with my mesh. There appears to be a 2D oval shape on the outside of the model.

[image: oval shape on outside of mesh blender screenshot]

I'm not sure how to fix this.
I think it might have something to do with the subdivision surface modifier.

Comment: It looks like you might have duplicated some faces in that area. Try pressing `M` (merge) in the 3D viewport and select "by distance".

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I have figured out why.
The reason for this was that there was two extra faces? I think I might have extruded it by accident and didn't notice.

[image]

[image]